# how to migrate already exist golang project from go path to go module

Tags: go, go-modules

i have an already exist golang project want to migrate it to go mod, i followed this article [migrate to go modules](https://blog.golang.org/migrating-to-go-modules) but the problem here is i get this error every time i try to run or build the project

> cannot load go-temp/pkg/custom_package: malformed module path "go-temp/pkg/custom_package": missing dot in first path element

**custom_package** is an internal package and imported in several other packages

```golang
 import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "go-temp/pkg/custom_package"
    "go-temp/src/another_package"
    "go-temp/src/routes"
    "log"
    "os"
   )
```

how to solve this problem without walking through all this packages and change them from relative path to absolute path start with the module domain

Comment: What is `go-temp`? That's not a valid module name, as the error says. Go modules also shouldn't have `pkg` or `src` directories. Can you provide more info on your module structure?

Comment: it's the directory that contain all the packages , it's an old project built  before go module .

Comment: Even before modules, no import should have `pkg` or `src` in it. So it's still unclear what your project/module structure is.

Answer (score -1):

A simple `go mod init PROJECT_NAME` into the directory can be enough. Then `go clean` and `go build`

`go-temp` have to be a go module created using `go mod init go-temp`. Than you need to import it using the `go.mod` file.

NOTE: i don't know if "go-temp" is a valid name, probably the bar into name is not allowed.